# Why the string length is different for the same string in input field and as static value of variable string in JS

Tags: javascript

I am getting two different string length in javascript. One from the input field and the other from the direct js string value. For example  if I set the input field value as same as the static input in js variable `str2` i,e: `\u002Funits\u002F0004\u002F62a345b3-ead7-4d06-a65b-243fc54780ec`. I get different string length (63 and 48)in the console for the same input from variable `str` and `str2`

```js
var checklen = function() {

  var str = document.getElementById("text").value;

  str = str.trim();


  console.log(str);
  console.log(str.length);


  var str2 = "\u002Funits\u002F0004\u002F62a345b3-ead7-4d06-a65b-243fc54780ec";
  console.log(str2.length);

}
```

```html
<div id='form'>
  text <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />

  <input type="button" onclick="checklen()" value="check">
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

because when you directly  put the string into javascript like this

```
  var str2 = "\u002Funits\u002F0004\u002F62a345b3-ead7-4d06-a65b-243fc54780ec";
```

javascript will interpret `\` as special character escape hence the result will be as shown in `colsole.log` 
however if you put two `\\` the first one cancel the second one and the string would behave as expected

```js
var checklen = function() {

  var str = document.getElementById("text").value;

  str = str.trim();


  console.log(str);
  console.log(str.length);


  var str2 = "\u002Funits\u002F0004\u002F62a345b3-ead7-4d06-a65b-243fc54780ec";
  console.log(str2.length);
  console.log(str);
  console.log(str2);


var str3 = "\\u002Funits\\u002F0004\\u002F62a345b3-ead7-4d06-a65b-243fc54780ec";
  console.log("str len: ", str.length);
  console.log("str2 len: ", str2.length);
  console.log("str3 len: ", str3.length);
  console.log("str: ", str);
  console.log("str2: ", str2);
  console.log("str3: ", str3);
}
```

```html
<div id='form'>
  text <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />

  <input type="button" onclick="checklen()" value="check">
</div>
```

Comment: @threeFatCat :D you can write yours as well, if it gives a better view to the post. Otherwise, you can edit my answer to make it better answer.

Comment: Just like Andam said. "\u002" is a kind of UTF-8 (HEX), will be converted to "/".

Comment: How the second str2 length is calculated to 48 ?

Comment: @alamin_cse07 the javascript will decode \u002f into / since you have three of these codes in your string and each one of them is 6 character in length it will remove 18 characters and instead on them it will add 3 of / in their place into your string hence 63 - 18 + 3 = 48